# Batch Script - Findstr "/n" flag?

Tags: batch-file, replace

I found a example of what I wanted to do online, which was search a text file for a string and replace only that string and write out to a file. Which sort-of works...

The script does replace the correct text. But, its printing line numbers, which I don't want. However, if I remove the **\n** flag from findstr, it only prints lines containing data, and lines that aren't comments *(*i.e. beginning with ";;")*.

How do I use findstr to print all the lines without the line numbers?

```
@echo off &setlocal

set "search=string to replace"
set "replace=replace string with me"
set "textfile=input.ini"
set "newfile=output.ini"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/n` switch is required to keep the empty lines, so if want the empty lines in input be copied to the output you should not remove `/n` switch from `findstr`  otherwise you do not need `findstr` and can directly read file with `FOR`. instead you can remove the line numbers by this modified code of yours:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "search=string to replace"
set "replace=replace string with me"
set "textfile=input.ini"
set "newfile=output.ini"

(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    if "%%j" NEQ "" (
        set "line=%%j"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    ) else (
     echo(
    )
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"
```

Also there is no need for `set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"` you can directly pass `!line:%search%=%replace%!` to `echo`

Or you can get ride of `findstr` altogether and simply write the `FOR` loop as below but you will loos empty lines

```
(for /f "usebackq delims="eol^= %%i in ("%textfile%") do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

Please note that in `"usebackq delims="eol^=` **there must be no spaces** between the quotation mark(") and `eol`. It is not a typo.

This is to disable the default eol character(;) so the lines that beginning semicolon(;) will not be ignored by `FOR /F` command

Comment: Hi,  slight problem with this solution with findstr is that delims=:  will drop any leading : character on your lines. This is a problem for me since I'm trying to find all labels in a batch file by line number ! So I need both empty lines and lines that start with ":" !

Comment: @Shodan the solution in certainly not suited for your specific problem or any other specific circumstances. It's not a solution but a more clear description of how things work. But to slightly address your specific need you can keep track of line numbers using a counter and then remove the lines numbers with somthing like `!var:*%%c:=!` in which `%%c` stands for the value of the counter variable that is temporarily captured by another `FOR` command. Correct handling of the delayed expansion and assignments is crucial but another story.